# bind dynamic menu from database to a layout page and show it for all the pages of asp net core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a layout page in asp net core application.And I want to bind dynamic menu from database to it which is shown on all the pages of the project having various controllers and models as well. Here is my code for layout page:-

```
 @Html.Partial("_Menu", Model)
```

here is my partial view page named _Menu:-

```
@if (ViewBag.Industries != null)
{
    @foreach (var items in ViewBag.Industries)
    {
        <li class="level0 parent drop-menu">
            <a href="index.html"><span>@items.IndustryName</span></a>
            <ul class="level1">
                @foreach (var subitems in items.MasterProductCategory)
                {
                    <li class="level1 first parent"><a href="404error.html"><span>@subitems.CategoryName</span></a></li>
                }
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
}
```

and here is my controller for fetching the menu items in home controller:-

```
public ActionResult _Menu()
        {
            ViewBag.Industries = _context.MasterIndustry.Include(u => u.MasterProductCategory).ToList();
            return PartialView("_Menu", ViewBag.Industries);
        }
```

The Issue is that While debugging the solution it is moving from layout page to the partial page but it is not invoking the menu controller.and giving result that viewBag.Industry is empty.where i have to write menu controller so that for every page and every controller it invokes menu controller to get the desired result. Or if there is any better way to solve this. Please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One needs to globalize the menu on every controller and force it to execute before any action.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    // Your logic here...
    BindMenuItems();
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
}

public IActionResult BindMenuItems()
{
    ViewBag.Industries = _context.MasterIndustry.Include(u => u.MasterProductCategory).ToList();
    return View();
}
```

Layout Page:

```
@if(ViewBag.Industries != null)
{                       
    @foreach(var items in ViewBag.Industries)
    { 
        <li class="level0 parent drop-menu">
            <a href="index.html"><span>@items.IndustryName</span></a>
            <ul class="level1">                                
                @foreach(var subitems in items.MasterProductCategory)
                { 
                    <li class="level1 first parent"><a href="404error.html"><span>@subitems.CategoryName</span></a></li>
                }                                  
            </ul>
        </li>
    }
}
```

Hope this will help others who are facing the same issue. I don't know whether it is business standard or not, but it helps me to get a solution for instant.

Answer (score 0):

[`Partial Views`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial) dont using self controllers. Use [`View Component`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components) and then invoke to your layout